# How to migrate from httpd 2.2 to the conf.modules.d directory in httpd 2.4?

Tags: apache, centos, configuration-files, httpd.conf, server-migration

I have recently begun upgrading my `httpd` version 2.2 from an older server with RHEL 4 to RHEL 7 that ships with `httpd` version 2.4.

One of the changes I noticed, was the **`conf.modules.d`** directory that has the following files:

```
00-base.conf
00-dav.conf
00-lua.conf
00-mpm.conf
00-proxy.conf
00-systemd.conf
01-cgi.conf
10-php.conf
```

I'm unable to find documentation on the official Apache upgrade logs about the above directory changes. Do I simply find out the equivalent files from the older **`conf.d`** in version 2.2, and copy over to **`conf.modules.d`**?

But another problem then is that the newer 2.4 **`conf.d`** directory has a `php.conf` as well in addition to the `10-php.conf` within **`conf.modules.d`** , so I don't know which file to copy over from the older 2.2 files.

What is the purpose of this new directory?

Comment: If you look at our main httpd.conf, you probably have `Include` statements for those files.  In 2.4 they split the configuration into many files instead of all in one file.

Comment: @Nic3500 RedHat has something under their documentation, but I'm still unclear how it was being done before:
https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/7/html/system_administrators_guide/ch-web_servers

Comment: In the older version, they put the included configuration files under conf.d.  Now they are under conf.modules.d.  But you cannot just copy 2.2 config to a 2.4 and expect all to work.  Look at https://httpd.apache.org/docs/trunk/upgrading.html, they list they changes that must be made.  The main changes are in access control, but the majority should work.  I would keep the 2.4 configs as a base and integrate your site specific confgs into it.

Comment: There are many differences moving from 2.2 to 2.4, refer "[https://httpd.apache.org/docs/trunk/upgrading.html](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/trunk/upgrading.html)" for the guidelines. And, `10-php.conf` just mentioned the modules that needs to be loaded on startup whereas `php.conf` has some configuration details that allow php files to execute.

Comment: @Nic3500 could you please write that as an answer, because that is in relation to my question. I already read on the upgrading guide back when I posted the question but couldn't find info that you gave. Thanks

Comment: Done :-)  have a look.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the older version, they put the included configuration files under conf.d. Now they are under conf.modules.d.

But you cannot just copy 2.2 config to a 2.4 and expect all to work. Look at 
[Apache Upgrading 2.2 to 2.4](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/trunk/upgrading.html).  There they list the changes that must be made.

The main changes are in access control, but the majority should work. I would keep the 2.4 configs as a base and integrate your site specific configurations into it.